# sqlalchemy count descendants

Tags: python, sql, sqlalchemy

I have a self referential sqlalchemy model. It's very simple, it's a table of posts, each post can be a reply to another post. there's no depth limit.

```
class Post(db.Model):
    post_id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    parent_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('post.post_id')
    [...]
    replies = db.relationship('Post')
```

I need a way to count the number replies a post has. as deep as possible. so replies to replies to replies etc count as a reply..

any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have here is basically a [tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_%28data_structure%29) stored using a [adjacency list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjacency_list).

While what you want can be done using [a relatively simple recursive function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal#Depth-first_2), it's very inefficient, because you need to query the database multiple times to obtain the children of each post.

Another, slightly more complex, way of storing this type of data is called the Modified Preorder Tree Tranversal (MPTT). It's much more efficient, since you can obtain the data you want  from any tree in a single query - you can even even count the number of replies without fetching any actual reply data.

You can find a very good overview of adjacency lists vs MPTT [on this article](http://www.sitepoint.com/hierarchical-data-database/).

If you don't want to implement this yourself, for SQLAlchemy in particular you can use [SQLAlchemy-ORM-tree](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/SQLAlchemy-ORM-tree/)